Intermediate SignalCatchingEvent fails with: "Execution has not subscribed to a signal event"
I am using the Activiti 6 workflow engine in my project and I want a way to send the workflow back to the "Client reviews estimate" task any time a contractor makes changes to a job. The changes are made outside the workflow, so I need to notify the process instance externally (via the Activiti Java API) and asynchronously (the workflow is not sitting there waiting on that signal) such that it can send it back to the aforementioned task that will allow the client to approve the changes a contractor makes to job proposal.
Here is the applicable part of my process diagram. The intermediate signal catching event BPMN construct is shown circled in orange. This is what I understand to be the correct workflow diagram element to use to allow a process instance to receive external messages asynchronously.

Here is the beginning portion of the BPMN 2.0 XML document for the contractor job process showing the signal declarations:

Below is the intermediate signal catching event declaration:

Here is the error produced while attempting to trigger the signal from the Activiti RuntimeService in the Java API:

I have tried switching between:
signalEventReceived("clientChangedJobSignal", processInstance.getId())
and
signalEventReceivedAsync("clientChangedJobSignal", processInstance.getId())
as I don't really understand the difference too well. Neither one works. I still get the same error that says:

org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Execution '5' has not
subscribed to a signal event with name 'clientChangedJobSignal'.

